# Excel, Formula to check availability. Check and copy values to cover each position

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following table:
[image]

The formula I am looking for should do this:
Starting from Prod. 2 in the second table (I4):
It should check if the cell A4 is blank, then look for a value in B4 if B4 has a value copy it to I4. If A4 is not blank, no need to look for value and no need to copy it, just leave I4 blank.

In J4 it should check if cells A4:B4 are blank before looking for value C4.
...
The last one M4 should check cells A4:E4 before checking values in F4 to copy it (if there is) into M4.

The table should represent maximal availibilty. The objective is to check if there is already an value in the column before, if yes no need to act, if blank, yes look up and copy value from next column. This goes on until last column M4.
The values within in the cells are not of importance. It should simply check if like this: if there is nothing in cells A4:E4 then look up F4 and if in F4 there is a value then copy it to M4 if F4 is also blank, then M4 keeps blank.
Like this for every column. L4 would be like this--> check if A4:D4 have a value if every cell is blank then look up E4 and if E4 has value then copy it to L4 if not, leave L4 blank.....

Answer (score 0):

I hope this gets some rep..

**Column h :  Prod 1**

```
=IF(A4="";"";A4)
```

**Column i :  Prod 2**

```
=IF(H4="";IF(B4="";"";B4);"")
```

**Column j :  Prod 3**

```
=IF(AND(H4="";I4="");IF(C4="";"";C4);"")
```

**Column k :  Prod 4**

```
=IF(AND(H4="";I4="";J4="");IF(D4="";"";D4);"")
```

**Column l :  Prod 4**

```
=IF(AND(H4="";I4="";J4="";K4="");IF(E4="";"";E4);"")
```

**Column m :  Prod 6**

```
=IF(AND(H4="";I4="";J4="";K4="";L4="");IF(F4="";"";F4);"")
```

Comment: how would column K and L and M look like? The formula for M does not work

Comment: Answer updated. I have supplied 3 different solutions for cell verification. Do you think you can figure out the rest from here?

Comment: Man, it does not work. Sorry but is not what I was looking for.

Comment: You have to specify what is not working. For me it's working in the context of: if A4 or B4 or both are blank, the value of C4 will be in J4, if C4 is blank, J4 will be blank as well.

Comment: Column I works but J does not. No single value appears

Comment: Do you have a value in A,B or C?

Comment: From what you explained the desired output :
J4 is blank as B is not blank
but
J8 is the value of C8, as A8,B8 are blank and C is not correct?

Comment: The logic behind it is, if I have got no value (blank) in A4, the formula looks in the next column B4 and finds an value and copies it into I4. If in B4 would not contain a value, it goes on until E4 where it finds an value an copies it into L4. It is important that once a value is found in any of the columns, no other column must contain a value. Once checked for value and found, the job is done. In other words in the matrix, everything I got in column a is considered done so no other column must contain a value in this row. If row x in column A  is blankl >look for value in this row in Col B

Comment: the formula with count does not work. Is there a possibility to extend the first formula to a range? Something like "=IF(A4:C4="";IF(D4="";"";D4);"")" does not work either.

Comment: What you actually want is **only the first** prod-value  in the range A-F to appear in the respective range H-M. Crystal?

Comment: Exactly. Thats it! I tried with count but it wont work. The first formula works but only for the second column I

Comment: Alright, give me a sec to update, btw its COUNTA not COUNT :)

Comment: How about now Conti?